# Who should be managing email call-to-actions? Frontend or Backend?

Tags: rest, email

In our current company we are decoupling the current architecture of our platform into separated backend and frontend. The backend is the one in charge of delivering the emails when the frontend application makes certain requests to the API.

We came across the problem to decide who should be the one in charge of completing the email call-to-actions.

For example, we are sending an email to a User asking them if they want to accept or decline an offer. Our question is, when the User clicks one of those actions:

1. Should the link point to the backend, make the action in the backend and then redirect the User to the frontend?
2. Should the link point to the frontend, make the action in the frontend through the API and continue the flow in the frontend?
3. Other solution?

Comment: So, what do you end up with?

Comment: We ended up using a third-party application, Customer.IO, where the marketing team can change the copy of emails without any engineering efforts. We send backend events via Segment and then directly to Customer.IO